# How to calculate divergence of the given function?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

The vector function is:

$$\mathbf{v}=\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$

$r$ is the magnitude of position vector and

$\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the unit vector along the position vector

Now divergence will be

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}={\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)}\cdot \mathbf{v}$$

How is this evaluated?

Comment: Can you write $\mathbf{v}$ and $r$ in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: we can convert r the magnitude of position vector to x,y,z by (x^2+y^2+z^2)^1/2

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: yes little bit...

Comment: i think the conversion of (1/r^2) **r**  to x, y, z  form is-( **i** + **j** + **k** )/(x^2+y^2+z^2)  may be wrong.

Comment: $\mathbf{v} = x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k}$

Comment: unable to do the differentiation

Comment: I think our comments are racing past each other, but if you're saying you don't know how to find the derivatives of functions like $x/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, you need to stop and learn that.  Nothing in vector calculus is going to get easy if you don't know how to take derivatives.

Comment: The divergence I find after differentiating is -2x-2y-2z but it should be zero

Comment: @helpMePlz  How do you know that it should be zero?

Comment: from the book i am studying

Comment: @MarkViola I got it when I use spherical coordinates system it is zero.....I think I did some mistake when  converting to cartesian coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without switching coordinate systems, this is my favorite method, since it breaks down the identity into small pieces.

Let $\mathbf{r} = x\mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k}$, and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.  Notice that
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{v} &= \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}\\
    \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} &= r^2 \\
    \nabla r &= \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} \\
    \nabla \cdot \mathbf{r} &= 3 \\
\end{align*}
We can use the product rule for the divergence, and the power rule for the gradient:
\begin{align*}
    \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} &= \nabla\cdot(r^{-3} \mathbf{r}) \\
    &= (\nabla r^{-3}) \cdot \mathbf{r} + r^{-3} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{r} \\
    &= (-3)r^{-4}\nabla r \cdot \mathbf{r} + 3 r^{-3} \\
    &= (-3)r^{-4}(r^{-1}\mathbf{r})\cdot \mathbf{r} + 3 r^{-3} \\
    &= (-3)r^{-5}\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} + 3r^{-3} \\
    &= (-3)r^{-5}r^2 + 3r^{-3} \\
    &= (-3)r^{-3} + 3r^{-3} = 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Note, in Cartesian coordinates $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\mathbf{r} = x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+z\hat{\mathbf{k}}$.

So, we have $\mathbf{v} =  \left( \frac{1}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat{r}} \right)$. It might be instructve to write the unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}} = \frac{\mathbf{\mathbf{r}}}{r}$. This is the definition of the unit vector.

Putting that together we have

$$\mathbf{v} =  \left( \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}  \right), $$

which is equivalent to

$$\mathbf{v} = \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\hat{\mathbf{i}}+
\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\hat{\mathbf{j}}+\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\hat{\mathbf{k}}.$$

The divergence is then given by

$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \right) \cdot \left( \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}},
\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \right).$$

Can you take it from here?

As some of the comments mention, using spherical coordinates is far easier in this example.